# OpenGL Hooking Vertex Buffer

Tags: c++, opengl

Situation: I'm injecting into an application that uses Vertex Buffers to render models. I want to get the exact coordinates of every vertex of every model. I've used detours to track information passed to the client. Basically all info goes through me first before it hits that application.

Question: I've intercepted all OpenGL calls, how can I get the vertex buffer data?

The code I have looks like:

```
struct BufferObject  //My struct to hold all data gathered.
{
    GLint ID;
    GLsizei Size;
    GLboolean Reserved;
    GLenum Type, Usage;
    const GLvoid* BufferPointer;
};

BufferObject CurrentBuffer;
std::vector<BufferObject> ListOfBuffers;

DLL_EXPORT __stdcall void MyHook_glBindBufferARB(GLenum target, GLuint buffer)
{
    BufferBound = true;
    CurrentBuffer.Type = target;  //Save what kind of buffer it is.
    CurrentBuffer.ID = buffer;    //Save the buffer ID.

    (*original_glBindBufferARB) (target, buffer);
}

DLL_EXPORT __stdcall void MyHook_glBufferDataARB(GLenum target, GLsizeiptrARB size, const GLvoid *data, GLenum usage)
{
    if (BufferBound && CurrentBuffer.Type == target && target == GL_ARRAY_BUFFER)   //If it's vertices, save them.. All the X, Y, Z's.
    {
        BufferBound = false;
        CurrentBuffer.Size = size;   //Save the buffer size.
        CurrentBuffer.BufferPointer = data; //Not sure if to do this or to use memcpy or what.. :S
        CurrentBuffer.Usage = usage;  //Save it's usage.
        ListOfBuffers.push_back(CurrentBuffer);  //Add the current buffer to the list.
    }
    (*original_glBufferDataARB) (target,  size, data, usage);
}

DLL_EXPORT __stdcall void MyHook_glVertexPointer(GLint size, GLenum type, GLsizei stride, const GLvoid *pointer)
{
    ModelRendering = true;
    CurrentModel.Stride = stride;  //A model is being rendered so save it's stride.
    CurrentModel.NullVertex = (pointer == NULL);
    CurrentModel.VertexPointer = pointer;   //This seems to always be NULL.
    ListOfModels.push_back(CurrentModel);

    (*original_glVertexPointer) (size, type, stride, pointer);
}

DLL_EXPORT __stdcall void MyHook_glDrawElements(GLenum mode, GLsizei count, GLenum type, const GLvoid *indices)
{
    if (ModelRendering)  //If one of the models I'm tracking is being rendered.
    {
        Model* ModelPtr = &ListOfModels.back();
        ModelPtr->ID = 0;
        ModelPtr->TriangleCount = count / 3;    //Should be correct.

        if (!ModelPtr->NullVertex)  //If vertexpointer was not null.
        {
            const GLfloat* Pointer = static_cast<const GLfloat*>(ModelPtr->VertexPointer); //Should be used to iterate each vertex? Gotten from vertex pointer..
            ModelPtr->X = *Pointer + ModelPtr->Stride;
            ModelPtr->Y = *Pointer + ModelPtr->Stride + sizeof(GLfloat);    //I think?
            ModelPtr->Z = *Pointer + ModelPtr->Stride + (2 * sizeof(GLfloat));
        }
        else        //It's rendering from the vertex buffer.. This is what I need.
        {
            ModelPtr->X = *(ListOfBuffers[CurrentBuffer.ID].BufferPointer) + ModelPtr->Stride;
            ModelPtr->Y = *(ListOfBuffers[CurrentBuffer.ID].BufferPointer) + ModelPtr->Stride + sizeof(GLfloat);
            ModelPtr->Z = *(ListOfBuffers[CurrentBuffer.ID].BufferPointer) + ModelPtr->Stride + sizeof(GLfloat);
        }

        if ((ModelPtr->Stride == Stride) && Overlay)
            original_glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
        else
            original_glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    }
    else
        original_glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    (*original_glDrawElements) (mode, count, type, indices);
}
```

I've used a struct to hold all the data I've gathered for each buffer and a vector to hold a list of all buffers. How can I get the data though? It has to be possible because gDEBugger can do it :S.

This is what the application does:

```
//Creates a buffer and stores data in it.
glGenBuffersARB(1, 0x0BAD9664)
glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 49)
glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 97996, 0x266AF026, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

//Calls buffer 49 and starts to draw it.
glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 49)
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 24, 0x00000000)
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY)
glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 24, 0x0000000C)
glBindBufferARB(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 56)
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 1326, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0x00000000);
```

Comment: "Basically all info goes through me first before it hits that application." Assuming they don't map the buffer, of course.

Comment: Not sure what you mean but it should go through me as well. I've hook ALL functions + WGL functions + Ext functions. The buffers aren't mapped though. I've checked every single call. All 30k of them with a Control + F.

Comment: You can hook whatever you want, but that's not going to stop someone from [mapping the buffer and writing to it with regular memory accesses](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object#Mapping).

Comment: @NicolBolas: While that is true I don't see what would stop him from getting the changed contents of the buffer after the writing is finished (on `glUnmapBuffer`).